# "Cannot open load file" error when loading autoload file

Tags: emacs, autoload

I have a file functions called "myloaddefs.el". It has magic coments and forms under them just like the one below.

```
;;;###autoload
(defun an-awesome-function '()
   (interactive)
  "A descriptive comment." t)

;;; other descriptive comments and forms...
```

It's full path is `~/.emacs.d/core/myloaddefs.el`. 
I also have an autoloads file whose full path is `~/.emacs.d/.local/autoloads.el`. I store its path in the variable `my-autoload-file`.

Before calling `update-file-autoloads`, `my-autoload-file` only has an empty comment `;;` (making sure it's non-empty to avoid an error). Calling `update-file-autoloads` as I do below returns nil. And it when I check the `my-autoload-file` it was indeed updated with autoloads. Loading the 'my-autoload-file`returns`t` and also seems successful.

```
(update-file-autoloads (concat my-core-dir "myloaddefs.el") t my-autoload-file) ; => nil
(load-file my-autoload-file) ; => t
```

However after calling an autoloaded interactive function with, `M-x an-awesome-function` I get `"Cannot open load file: no such file or directory" "../core/myautoloads"`. This confuses me greatly because the directory and the file do exist. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to your autoload file needs to be on your load path since you are using relative paths to load the libraries (eg. `../core/autoloads`). I would use `expand-file-name` anywhere you are creating a path instead of building them using `concat`.

Try `(push (expand-file-name ".local" "~") load-path)` prior to calling `an-awesome-function` (whose definition is incorrect).

Comment: I changed the definiton so it's not correct. Just a minor correction: I think it's supposed to be `(push (expand-file-name ".local" "~/.emacs.d/") load-path)` but I had no problems understanding what you meant.

Comment: Also out of curiosity, is there a way to autoload using the absolute path? There is no parameters in `update-file-autoloads` or `update-directory-autoloads` to do this. Only way I could think if is using `replace-string` to replace relative with absolute path after autoload file is created.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could find out by calling `edebug-defun` on `update-file-autoloads` and stepping through the code